Spawn a 'daemon' process from Ruby that doesn't exit when ruby exits
I'd like to spawn a process mycmd from Ruby:

I'd like Ruby to block until mycmd writes BOOTED to stdout.
When Ruby exits mycmd should keep running as a daemon.

I have Ruby blocking until mycmd writes BOOTED, but I can't get mycmd to hang around as a daemon.
stdin, stdout, stderr, process_status = Open3.popen3("mycmd --whatever")
puts "Starting mycmd, pid=#{process_status.pid}"

# Block until mycmd prints "BOOTED":
stdout.each_line do |line|
  break if line.include?("BOOTED")
end

Process.detatch(process_status.pid)

# And now our ruby process exits, killing mycmd as it dies
# How can I keep mycmd running even when Ruby exits?

Things I've tried:

Open3.popen3("nohup mycmd") # mycmd exits with ruby
Open3.popen3("mycmd &") # mycmd exits with ruby
Open3.popen3("mycmd > /dev/null 2>&1") # mycmd does NOT exit when ruby exits (yay), but I can't read from stdout to wait for BOOTED


Redirect mycmd output to a file and wait for BOOTED in the file instead? That way mycmd will stay detached from the terminal but you can still catch BOOTED from the file. This is the simplest solution. Other solutions will require more elaborate programming.

call Process.daemon in the child process?

Process.daemon (and many other Process methods) are not guaranteed to be implemented on every system (see Windows)

I like Alex's idea but unfortunately I don't control the source to mycmd. Maybe I could wrap mycmd in wrap_mycmd.rb, which calls Process.daemon .... and.... can't quite make this work.

I implemented this using a file as per Casper's suggestion. I don't love it, because I now have to poll a file, and the output file will be quite large, but after trying lots of elaborate programming with lots of edge cases (the most extreme, but also succesful was using ptrace to actually modify stdout/stderr in the child process, but linux only), I think I'm back to "very simple even if ugly" as best.

Seth, how about pipe the output through grep looking for BOOTED, and redirect that to the file? No big files any more, though only works on Linux.

The likely problem here is that the standard output streamsof your child process are owned by the parent process. Once the parent process is killed, the stdout and stderr descriptors in the child process are invalid, and any attempt to use them will fail with an error such as:
Broken pipe @ rb_io_flush_raw - <STDOUT>

Since it sounds like you're attempting to launch the child as a daemon, it would be best to avoid trying to directly capture the stdout or stderr of the child. As mentioned in the comments by Casper, setting the child stdout and stderr to a file is reasonable, and this could also be done in the child process via STDOUT.reopen(...)
